# Revert from ASP.NET MVC 3 to MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, revert

I've researched this, but have yet to find a viable answer. I've run into serious problems when trying to upgrade to MVC 3. Without going into a lengthy explanation, I simply need to revert back to MVC 2. Due to restrictions in discussing work projects, I can't list all the "why's", but this is a requirement. I add this in because I saw a similar thread in which all of the answers revolved around why this should happen and suggestions to make changes so MVC 3 could stay. I can't do this.

I used the upgrade utility, so I assume many changes were made that I'm not aware of. I finally got the application to build after changing the project references to System.Web.Mvc version 2, but the page won't load, giving this error:

The view at '~/Some/Shared/View.ascx' must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl

I can of course Google this and fix it, but I'm afraid that I'm going to encounter myriad build or runtime errors after doing it, and was hoping for an easier way to revert. Any help in doing this would really be appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you just get the MVC 2 version out of your source control?

Comment: Sounds like bad business decisions are making you jump through hoops to do something technically backwards. Obviously I can't say this for sure, but I'm guessing this will bite you again in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As with any kind of upgrade, it's always best to plan in contingency for any issues that may occur, and back your work up prior to upgrade.

Hindsight, however, is not what you're looking for. Do you not have source control? Can you not roll-back to a previous date or change set? If not, you're pretty much going to have to go through every issue one at a time, and regression test your entire application. I don't know of any software that can revert to a previous major version (i.e. usually includes major breaking changes) without quite a bit of hassle...

Just bite the bullet and put it down to a learning experience, and make sure you get the project in to source control and implement a backup system ASAP. Even my personal projects are backed up to SVN on my NAS!